# How does one handle a text change event for a UITextField with Swift 4?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitextfield, swift4

From Objective C to later versions of swift, I have successfully used the `editingChanged` method to detect when text is changed in a `UITextField`.

However it does not appear to work as of Swift 4.

I have also tried the follow per several docs online:

`textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)`

And this also fails to hit the provided "@objc" function.

There is now of course the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method but the limitation here is that this runs before, not after, a text change happens and means that any mutating can't happen until after it returns.

Would appreciate any thoughts here, extremely frustrating that such trivial access to a core component is so elusive.

Comment: may be you're returning false inside **shouldChangeCharactersIn**

Comment: Thank you for your thought @Sh_Khan but I can confirm `shouldChangeCharactersIn` does indeed work, per the question it just gets hit before not after the text changes.

Comment: @JohnDoe yes it work but if you're returning false inside it then **textFieldDidChange** won't be called even if correct implementation

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

And then use:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) { 
  //do whatever
}
```

I am currently using that in one of my apps.

If it doesn't work, there is another issue such as returning false in `shouldChangeCharactersIn` and you will have to show more code in order to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Please use    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)  instead of  UIControlEvents.editingChanged